# Dynamic Combo box values in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

Here I am having a set of dynamic combo box.

```
<select id='attend_1' class='form-control' name='attend_1' style='width:100px;'><option value='1'>Present</option><option value='0'>Absent</option></select>
<select id='attend_2' class='form-control' name='attend_2' style='width:100px;'><option value='1'>Present</option><option value='0'>Absent</option></select>
```

In C#, while getting the value,

```
for(int i;i<=2;i++) 
{
 response.write("attend_"+i.SelectedValue);

}
```

Then how to get values of respective combo box?

Comment: look at the Form collection on your Request object. you will figure out which one it is from that. also how are you creating it dynamically? why are you not using the ASP.NET drop down list? or is it being generated from the UI side?

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide enough information, like where the dynamic filling comes, how do you access, and on what events you need values. Will be easy to provide better solution on the basis of proper explanation.